# How to correctly allocate memory to a dynamic array of integers stored in a struct?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I have a function that sets values to a struct:

My struct:

```
struct entry {
    char key[MAX_KEY];
    int* values;
    size_t length;
    entry* next;
    entry* prev;
};
```

My function:

```
// Sets entry values
void command_set(char **commands, int arg_num) {
    struct entry e;
    e.length++;
    strcpy(e.key, commands[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < arg_num; i++) {
        e.values[i - 2] = atoi(commands[i]);
    }
}
```

where:

- **commands: is a array of strings
- arg_num: is how many strings are in the array
- key: is the name of the entry
- values: are integer values store in the entry

I run the code and I get a segmentation fault 11. I have narrowed it down to the line:

```
e.values[i -2] = atoi(commands[i]);
```

I assume that I have to use malloc to allocate memory as I don't appear to have gone out of bounds with my loop. I have tried to understand the correct way to allocate memory however I can't seem to get the syntax correct for allocating sizeof(int) to a dynamic array of integers.

I have tried:

```
e.values[i - 2] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and

```
e.values[i - 2] = (int) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and

```
e.values[i - 2] = malloc(sizeof(int *));
```

However I get the error:

```
incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning
  to 'int' from 'void *' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
```

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong with this, and also some baffling stuff like what you intend to do with `struct entry e` afterwards.  What do you want to achieve?  Helping you fix allocations and undefined behaviour might be irrelevant, because your current approach might be unsuitable.  Try showing a full example of this code being used in your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must allocate the whole array:

```
e.values = malloc(sizeof(int) * (arg_num - 2))
```

***Important:*** Remember to call `free` when you're done with the memory or you will have a memory leak.

---

You have another problem though, unrelated to the one you're asking about.

You do

```
struct entry e;
e.length++;
```

When the structure object `e` is defined, it is *uninitialized*, all its members will have an *indeterminate* value. Using such uninitialized data in any way except to initialize it will lead to *undefined behavior*. And you *do* use such uninitialized values when you do `e.length++`.

That increase simply doesn't make any sense in the code as you show it. On the other hand, that function doesn't make a lot of sense anyway since the variable `e` and all its data will simply "disappear" when the function returns. So I can only assume that it's not the complete function you show us.

To initialize the structure to all zeroes, simply do

```
struct entry e = { 0 };
```

Comment: This worked however may I ask are you then allocating the memory for the entire array of integers based on how many integers you'll have to input?

Comment: @joshuatvernon That's what the multiplication is for. You seem to use `arg_num - 2` values in the array, so I multiply the size of an `int` with that number.

Answer (score 2):

as your struct is as follows

```
struct entry {
    char key[MAX_KEY];
    int* values;
    size_t length;
    entry* next;
    entry* prev;
};
```

then you should allocate memory to it as

```
e.values =(int *)malloc(arg_num*sizeof(int));
```

like if you have 10 values then you are allocating 10*4 values to it.
and invoke free on it

```
free(e.values)
```

when the e or e.values is no more useful. for more information you can [see here](http://ccodinggeek.blogspot.in/search/label/malloc)

Answer (score 1):

Modify the function as below.

```
void command_set(char **commands, int arg_num) {
    struct entry e;
    e.length++;
    strcpy(e.key, commands[1]);
    //here is the memory allocation
    e.values = malloc(arg_num-1 * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < arg_num-1; i++) {
        e.values[i] = atoi(commands[i+1]);
    }
}
```